# Association used in default_value_for fails with FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

When using [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) in conjunction of [`default_value_for` gem](https://github.com/FooBarWidget/default_value_for), and when relying on an association that must be present like `belongs_to` to define the default value, I run in an error telling me that the relationship is not defined.

Here is a simplified example:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  default_value_for(:author_email) { |p| p.account.owner_email }

  belongs_to :account
end
```

```rb
# in my tests
create(:post, account: account)
```

When running the test, I get

> Failure/Error: default_value_for(:author_email) { |p| p.account.owner_email }
>
> NoMethodError:
> undefined method `owner_email' for nil:NilClass

It works fine when I use it in the context of the controller, but fails within the test, how can I make sure account is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use `initialize_with` in your factory, so when assigning the attributes, your association is already defined.

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    initialize_with { account.post.build(**attributes) }

    # insure there is always an account to build from
    association :account, factory: :account
  end
end
```